# Why is the time complexity of a dictionary O(n) not O(1)

Tags: swift, hashtable

[removeValueForKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1641348-removevalue)

> Complexity: O(n), where n is the number of key-value pairs in the dictionary.

As shown above, the `removeValue(forKey key: Key)` time complexity is O(n) not O(1).Why?

Comment: Somehow I think this is a mistake in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the value semantics of `Dictionary`. Removing a key-value pair potentially requires duplicating the data, making it a O(N) operation.

Comment: In that case, this would be the worst case complexity? However, why adding a key-value pair doesn't require making a duplicate?

Comment: @Sulthan That's a fair point. Either: all the documentation should state "true" time complexities, modeling the case where a mutation is happening on a uniquely referenced dictionary, or all the documentation should state the "worst case" time complexities (of at least `O(n)`), modelling the copy done by `ensureUnique()`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica That's what I was thinking too.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source Code of removeValue() you can see that it uses the ensureUnique() function, which creates a copy of the hashmap, if the item is not unique and therefore has Complexity of O(n)

Comment: could you link the source? If you have a single reference of the dictionary, there is no need to copy the data. Also, this would be the same even for adding values.

Comment: @Sulthan [DictionaryVariant.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b65777eabe49390b2afd04b8fb9a6c2e07a08d2f/stdlib/public/core/DictionaryVariant.swift#L395)